# Can't figure out why this big double inner join isn't working, but when split it does

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

Here is my queries split up that work perfectly fine...

```
    String sqlstatement = "SELECT WBLinkWebsiteID, WBLinkCategoryParentID, WBLinkTitle, WBLinkURL FROM WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE WHERE WBLinkCategoryID = ?";
    String[] args = { CategorySubID };
```

Part 2

```
    sqlstatement = "SELECT LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCountry, LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationType, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationUrl, "
+ "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle "
+ "FROM PREF_TABLE INNER JOIN "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE ON PREF_TABLE.Pref_LocationID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID "
+ "WHERE "
+ "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = '" + theSavedPref + "' ORDER BY LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity";
```

Now here is my attempt to combine the two instead of just having 2 go in row back to back and burn time/resources...

```
    String NewSqlstatement = "SELECT LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationWebsiteID, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCity, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationState, "      
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationCountry, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.locationUrl, "
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID, "
+ "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle, "   
+ "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkTitle, "
+ "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkURL "
+ "FROM PREF_TABLE INNER JOIN "   
+ "LOCATIONS_TABLE ON PREF_TABLE.Pref_LocationID = LOCATIONS_TABLE.LocationID "
+ "INNER JOIN WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE "
+ "ON WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkWebsiteID = PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID "
+ "WHERE "
+ "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = '" + theSavedPref + "'";
```

Now when I try to do my "SINGLE" way it keeps returning the WHOLE database of Locations in the LOCATIONS_TABLE query.  It doesn't do just the exact ones I need.

I know the query works, because I have tested it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ede97/2

Now I know my example on sqlfiddle is using MS Server 2014, but I assumed the syntax should be pretty much the same since its just standard SELECT with inner joins, but I could be wrong?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT - Fixed the SQLFIDDLE, I put the wrong statement in the example**

Comment: you should strip out all of the java. it's pretty much irrelevant since you're having trouble only with the SQL itself.

Comment: hope thats better i tried to format it too so its not so bunched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing your filter on WBLinkCategoryID in the combined query.  Shouldn't you have this:

`...
+ "INNER JOIN WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE "
+ "ON WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkWebsiteID = PREF_TABLE.Pref_WebsiteID "
+ "WHERE "
+ "WEBSITECATEGORY_TABLE.WBLinkCategoryID IN (<value1>,...,<valueN>) AND "
+ "PREF_TABLE.Pref_SavedTitle = '" + theSavedPref + "'";`

Comment: You are correct my friend!! Apparently thats all i was missing wow. Thanks a ton